# Select elements from a list according to their properties

Tags: c++, performance, search, data-structures

I am developing an application aimed to render a huge number of shapes. Each shape can be assigned to a specific *layer*.

I get the input data as a list of shapes, where for each shape I have a `string` property that represents the layer to which the shape belongs.

Now, I need to develop a method that allows me to select (draw) only those shapes that belong to a given list of selected layers. 
In pseudo-code:

```
void draw_if(sorted_list shapes, list<string> selected_layers)
{
   for each shape in shapes
   {
      if (shape.layer in selected_layers)
        shape.draw();
   }
}
```

The point is that I would like to perform this operation as fast as possible; therefore I need to choose the right data structures and a proper algorithm.

The list of selected layers is a list of strings (1÷100 different layers), but if needed for performance reasons, it could be converted to other data types.

The shapes are sorted according to their z-order.

Comment: You don't want to go through all the shapes when you want to update a specific layer, so a data structure like a HashMap<Layer,ArrayList<Shape>> would be helpful. But then you have to think, how fast do you need the following operations to work: insert, delete, search, sort? Delete, for example, would not generally gain by this arrangement, but with modification it could.

Comment: @EdwardDoolittle Your solution seems the fastest one, but I am not sure I can apply it. The problem is that the list of shapes is a sorted list (by z-order), thus I can't draw the shape in position 2 before the shape in position 1 because, if the two shapes occupy the same area, the outcome will be different (shape 1 over shape 2). Is there a way to use your hint given this constraint?

Comment: @gliderkite That's a solution where you form "selected shapes" in the order you want, consolidating the idea of shape selection with the shape itself. If you need Z-ordering of this sort, then you can form your "selected shapes" structure using a set, e.g. (basically a binary search tree). In that case, you are transferring the overhead primarily to the construction of the selection, but your drawing loop will be accelerated.

Comment: That said, if you want the fastest solution here for the drawing side of the loop at both an algorithmic and memory level (which isn't really micro as it can make orders of magnitudes of difference), you want your final selected shapes in a simple sorted array for spatial locality. Basically this kind of "selected shapes" solution prevents you from checking if a shape is selected at every frame you draw. It transfers that kind of overhead to forming the shape selection, not to drawing it potentially many times afterwards.

Comment: However, if your shape drawing needs to be Z-ordered and that Z-order is changing often (ex: for 3D elements or ones that are constantly changing), then you don't gain much by eliminating the selection check in the drawing loop. In that case, you want a solution like I proposed where you can check if a shape layer is selected in O(1) and with a simple array access. What matters here is not Z-ordering but what is static (not frequently changing) and what is dynamic (frequently changing). For example, if your drawing order is very dynamic but your layer selection is not, that's critical info.

Comment: @Ike I can assume that the z-order of my shapes is fixed, once the input has been parsed, while the list of the selected layers can change frequently.

Comment: @gliderkite Depending on how frequently those selected layers change (ex: if you draw 100 frames before the layer selection changes vs. just a few times before a change), it may or may not be beneficial to form a "selected shape list". If the selected layers are changing all the time, then probably not and you might do better to do a constant-time check for elements which are selected per-frame.

Comment: @gliderkite Basically if you form "selected shapes", that's more expensive initially but subsequent drawing is faster. So it's worth the extra cost if you're going to reuse that selected shapes list many times before updating it (ex: drawing it many times before either the Z-order or selected layers change). It's not worth it if you're just going to be updating it every frame, in which case it'd be better just to make the "is shape selected" query faster by turning it into constant-time against the selected layers, e.g.

Comment: Regardless of whether you form the selected shapes list or not, you can do your work a lot more efficiently if you can turn those `shape.layer` strings into indices or pointers into a layer list (which can store strings but also a selection flag). Then the query to see if a shape belongs to a selected layer turns into O(1), and something even faster than the most optimal hash. You also use less memory that way in addition to reduced processing by not duplicating the same strings over and over. That should aid you even if you form a memoized "selected shapes" list.

Comment: In that case, the slightly-expensive search to find which layer a shape belongs to is transferred to shape creation when it's created in a specific layer. There you might need to do a string search (could be logarithmic or even constant-time in a hash) to figure out the `shape.layer` index/pointer to store from a string input. But then all subsequent selection queries involving the shape turn into an O(1) array access when layers store a selection boolean/bit, including the creation of the "selected shapes" list (which can be a simple cache-friendly array when you have this kind of structure).

Comment: @gliderkite I updated my answer. It should give you the most optimal solution both at a micro/memory and algorithmic level provided that my one assumption is true: that you are not creating new shapes every single frame, just changing their z-order and/or selected layers or removing existing shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic intrusive solutions are often overlooked here in search of elaborate data structures and algorithms, but generally are the fastest.

Assuming you have no choice but to keep the selection separate, if you want a really fast solution, store a boolean selection flag in each layer (could be a single bit). When you form a selection, in addition to forming a list, set those flags. Deselecting a layer not only removes it from your selection, but sets that selection flag to false.

Next, turn those strings used to indicate selected layers into indices into a random-access structure (ex: `std::vector` or even a plain old array if the size can be determined at compile time), like so (simplified):

```
struct Layer
{
    string name;

    // Set this to true when the layer is selected, false 
    // when it is deselected. Use atomics if thread safety 
    // is required.
    bool selected;
};
```

... and turn `shape.layer` into an index (or pointer/iterator) to a layer. If you have no choice but to start with a layer string to identify which layer a shape belongs to because you are given string inputs initially (ex: from a file you are loading), then translate those strings into a layer index/pointer/iterator as you are creating the shapes from those string inputs. Use a hash table or at least std::set/map here (the string search on initial shape construction should be logarithmic or better) to convert those layer strings into layer indices/pointers/iterators.

If you need a layer selection list in addition to a layer selection state, then you can do this (pseudocode):

```
void select(Layer layer, LayerList& layer_selection)
{
     if (!layer.selected)
     {
          layer.selected = true;
          layer_selection.insert(&layer);
     }
}

void deselect(Layer layer, LayerList& layer_selection)
{
     if (layer.selected)
     {
          layer.selected = false;
          layer_selection.erase(&layer);
     }
}
```

... Where your layer selection stores indices/pointers/iterators to layers. Both the select and deselect list insertion/removal can be done in constant-time (even during worst-case) without hashing overhead and while preserving *insertion order* if you get fancy with the layer selection and use a fixed allocator (this is a complex subject involving placement new, unions, and memory pools so I'll delve into it if desired, but omit it for the time being for brevity).

Now your main pseudocode code turns into something like this:

```
void draw_if(list shapes, list layers)
{
   for each shape in shapes
   {
      if (layers[shape.layer].selected)
        shape.draw();
   }
}
```

... or this if you use pointers/iterators:

```
void draw_if(list shapes, list layers)
{
   for each shape in shapes
   {
      if (shape.layer->selected)
        shape.draw();
   }
}
```

It's hard to beat that in terms of performance as even the most optimal hash table cannot beat a simple indexed array access into memory you would still have to access in addition with the hash. Now if you can consolidate the idea of "selected shapes" and form selected shapes in advance through the process of selecting/deselecting layers, then you can do this:

```
void draw_selected(list selected_shapes)
{
   for each shape in selected_shapes
       shape.draw();
}
```

... which could be even faster provided that the extra cost of forming the selected shapes list is compensated by reusing it repeatedly before it has to change. Note that you still want to convert those strings into indices in this case, because you don't want your "selected shapes" list to have to be anything more than a simple array. To form the selected shapes list:

```
ShapeList selected_shapes(ShapeList all_shapes, LayerList layers)
{
     // Forming this in advance will help if it is reused for
     // numerous drawing frames before it needs to change (ex:
     // before the Z-order changes, before new elements are inserted
     // or existing ones removed, before the layer selection changes).
     ShapeList results;
     for each shape in all_shapes:
          if layers[shape.layer].selected)
             results.push_back(shape);
     return results;
}
```

... which is still even cheaper to form and access (due to spatial locality of a perfectly compact shape selection array) than a hash table thanks to that selection state we now store in layers.

This keeps everything cache-friendly and avoids expensive (relatively speaking) data structures like hash tables except during that initial string->index/pointer conversion part (which you only need to do when creating a shape from a string input). In this case, the only place that ever needs to do any kind of search (logarithmic or constant-time hash/trie) is when you convert those shape layer strings you get from user input into indices/pointers/iterators. Everything else is O(1) (even worst-case complexity) and doesn't even require hashing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a set instead of a list for the selected layers, that way a binary search can be performed to determine in shape.layer is in the selected layers, and insertion while preserving order is quick. Using a list would be inefficient for keeping the order required for binary search.

Another option is to figure out some hashing algorithm and just use a hash map.